# android builds fine in eclipse but not on jenkins ant

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, jenkins

I recently added the jars `joda-time-2.3` and `joda-time-2.3-sources`. My project continues to work fine on eclipse, but jenkins (ant) is breaking. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
[dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: 
[dx] com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/joda/time/Chronology; 
[dx] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:592) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:550) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:531) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexBuffers(DexMerger.java:168) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:186) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:300) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:232) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174) 
[dx] at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

**Edit**

How do I tell Jenkins/ant to stop looking once one source is found? assuming that is the problem.

Comment: My best guess would be that the joda-time-2.3-sources jar file contains class files as well.  You can verify that by simply examining the contents of the jar.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you need that jar (joda-time-2.3-sources.jar) in your project?  If you already have the compiled classes in the other jar, then you can simply remove joda-time-2.3-sources.jar and all should be well.

Comment: I tried your idea by removing `joda-time-2.3.jar` but then eclipse fails. I imagine if the source has classes, then I shouldn't need both.

Comment: The sources makes coding easier. I can just look at the docs.

Comment: You need one or the other.  Typically the non-source version is preferred.  The source version buys you nothing.  That source in not compiled in either Eclipse or Jenkins.  It is merely there for reference.... So, to address your problem, try using the other jar.  Also, do not forget to refresh your Eclipse project after making changes on the file system.

Comment: I agree that it is handy to have the source version, but it does not have to be part of your project.  Either that or you can simply use the source version instead of the pure class version.  Keep in mind that the source version slightly increases the size of your APK.  It is probably an insignificant increase, but the source files add no value to the API.

Answer (score 1):

joda-time-2.3-sources.jar includes class files as well.

The solution is to simply remove joda-time-2.3-sources.jar from your project.

joda-time-2.3.jar contains all of the classes you need.  The inclusion of the other jar is what is introducing multiple instances of the same classes.

Comment: No. If I only leave the source, eclipse will not compile. but if I remove the source and leave the other, eclipse compiles. But then after I sent to jenkins, I get the same failure message. So having both source and bin is not the problem. I am using ADT eclipse, why would things work on eclipse and on on ant (well, you get what I mean)?

Comment: Where are you putting these files?  In the <project_root>/lib directory?  If so, then I am puzzled why Eclipse would require the source jar.  Perhaps there are some classes in the source jar that are not in the other.  In any case, your goal should be to use only one jar.  If my suggestion does not work, then try just the source jar.  Also, be sure to refresh the Eclipse project after removing the other jar.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Remember I started with both `joda-time-2.3` and `joda-time-2.3-sources` (see OP). If I remove `joda-time-2.3` and keep `joda-time-2.3-sources`, eclipse does not work. So I keep `joda-time-2.3` and remove `joda-time-2.3-sources`. At this point, eclipse works fine, but ant fails all the same. So my conclusion is that having both was not the reason ant/jenkins was failing.